# AngularJS - Controller variable not updating from a service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this variable that is being controlled by the Factory and to update the Controller but it's not happening.

Here is what I have:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, AppFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.serverStatus = AppFactory.getStatus();
});

app.factory('AppFactory', function($timeout) {

  var AppFactory = {};
  var vm = this;
  vm.serverStatus = true;

  // Execute after 2 seconds of page start
  $timeout(function() {
    AppFactory.setStatus(false);
  }, 2000);

  AppFactory.setStatus = function(status) {
    console.log('Server set to ' + status);
    vm.serverStatus = status;

    // Getting server status = false
    AppFactory.getStatus();
  };


  AppFactory.getStatus = function() {
    console.log('Getting server status: ' + vm.serverStatus);
    return vm.serverStatus;
  };

  return AppFactory;
});
```

LIVE PLUNKER DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/62xGw7Klvbywp9TODWF4?p=preview

Do you think Directives would work better with 2-way-communication between a factory and controller?

Comment: Broadcast through events when server status changes.Make an EventEmitter service, and when status changes emit the value then subscribe in controller to get the latest value through this event. If you need further help I might provide code hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this edited the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/z6tdr5?p=preview

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope,$timeout, AppFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  $timeout(function() {
    AppFactory.setStatus(false);
    $scope.serverStatus = AppFactory.getStatus();
  }, 2000);

  $scope.serverStatus = AppFactory.getStatus();
});

app.factory('AppFactory', function($timeout) {

  var AppFactory = {};

  var serverStatus = true;

  // Execute after 2 seconds of page start


  return {
        getStatus: function () {

          //console.log('Getting server status: ' + vm.serverStatus);
          return serverStatus;
        },
        setStatus : function(status) {
          var vm = this;
        console.log('Server set to ' + status);
        serverStatus = status;

        // Getting server status = false
        vm.getStatus();
  }
  };
});
```

Comment: directives would be a better option if you need to manipulate DOM frequently and with complex structure/data  **EDIT** please take a note how the service functions are written. hope it helps

Comment: I would want the timeout call to be from the factory instead of the controller

Comment: @nn2  why do you need timeout in service any specific reason ?           because timeout from controller is also going to trigger on page load itself. do you want to trigger it in service? or just keep timeout function in service? you can just trigger timeout anytime from controller if you put it in service function. Optionally if you want it to trigger on any html div load you can do that to using ng-init . i can modify the example according to what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses events, e.g.:

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, AppFactory) {
  var vm = this; 

  $scope.$on('messageOne', function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
      $scope.serverStatus = data;
      $scope.$apply(); //I think $apply() is not needed here!
  });

  $scope.serverStatus = AppFactory.getStatus();


});

app.factory('AppFactory', function($timeout, $rootScope) {

  var AppFactory = {};
  var vm = this;
  vm.serverStatus = true;

  // Execute after 2 seconds of page start
  $timeout(function() {
    AppFactory.setStatus(false);
  }, 2000);

  AppFactory.setStatus = function(status) {
    console.log('Server set to ' + status);
    vm.serverStatus = status;

    // Getting server status = false
    //AppFactory.getStatus();

    $rootScope.$broadcast('messageOne', status);
  };


  AppFactory.getStatus = function() {
    console.log('Getting server status: ' + vm.serverStatus);
    return vm.serverStatus;
  };

  return AppFactory;
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/pARMnE3Wl0OeJezKuvLT?p=info